# Get item from breadcrumb/tree path (Adjacency model)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I understand you can get breadcrumbs/ tree path using a with a recursive CTE, but is it possible to select an item knowing the breadcrumb/tree?

```
id| name | parent_id
--------------------
0 | a    | null
1 | b    | 0
2 | c    | 1
3 | b    | 2
```

For example, if the breadcrumb looked like this: a/b/c/b, how would I be able to return the row with id 3 knowing this information?

Comment: Search for last part of breadcrumb (only if name is UNIQUE)? `SELECT * FROM tab where name = (some sql string func to get last part)`

Comment: Unfortunately names are not unique. Only the primary key id is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres just rocks.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0a6f4/27

The idea is to build the textbook recursive query which returns the path of each element in the tree, along with a "level" which represents the number of nodes from the root. You can also call it "depth".

Then, we turn the path 'a/b/c/b' into an ARRAY['a','b','c','b']... therefore indexing this array on [level] gives the name of the node we're looking for at each level.

```
WITH RECURSIVE h(id,name,parent_id,level,path,search_path) AS (
  SELECT  id,
      name,
      parent_id,
      1,
      ARRAY[name],
      ARRAY['a','b','c','b']
    FROM t WHERE parent_id IS NULL AND name = 'a'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT   t.id,
         t.name,
         t.parent_id,
         level+1,
         path || t.name,
         h.search_path
    FROM t JOIN h ON(t.parent_id=h.id)
      WHERE search_path[level+1] = t.name
)
SELECT *, path=search_path as match FROM h;
```

This returns the nodes from the requested path, in path order. I added a "match" column which becomes true when the requested row was found. If you only want this row, put the condition in the where, unless you want it to stop at the closest match and return it in case the path is not found, in which case you'll need to take the last row.

Funnily enough it should be possible to attempt this in MySQL by using session variables to transfer the parent_id from one row to the next, although MySQL has no arrays, so something like find_in_set() could work instead... would be kind of a hack...